# Google Sheets Query on a subset of columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

In google sheets, I need to query a subset of a table. 
The table range is `A1:K`, where column A is used for filtering.
I want to construct a query that looks like:

```
=query(A1:K,"Select B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K where A =x")
```

except I want it to look more like:

```
=query(A1:K,"Select B-K where A =x")
```

Is this possible?

In my case, I also need to be able to do this on averages, so:

```
=query(A1:K, "Select avg(B-K) where A=x label avg(B-K) ''")
```

The reason why I want to not spell this out is because this query is being generated dynamically. Is this possible, or must I generate the string for the query seperately?

Answer (score 1):

I think, the only way is to generate the string.

But if you make query like this:

```
=query({A1:K}, "Select ...")
```

then A-Z notation becomes Col1, Col2, Col3 and so on. You can take advantage of it:
use this formula to generate text "Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11":

```
=join(", ",ARRAYFORMULA("Col" & row(OFFSET(A2,,,10))))
```

And this formula will make text "AVG(Col2), AVG(Col3), AVG(Col4), AVG(Col5), AVG(Col6), AVG(Col7), AVG(Col8), AVG(Col9), AVG(Col10), AVG(Col11)":

```
=join(", ",ARRAYFORMULA("AVG(Col" & row(OFFSET(A2,,,10))&")") )
```

Also change `A2` and `10` in 2 formulas above to return different number of subsets.